# Recurring calendar events - only show next occurrence

Tags: calendar

My org has the same 3 meetings every week so a recurring calendar event was created by the admin assistant. When I use datasheet view, the events show up as starting in 2022 and ending in 2032. 2 questions:

1. How do show only future occurrences?
2. How do I show only the next occurrence?

Answer (score 0):

You can **edit ort create custom view** of libraries and lists to organize and show items that are important to you. You can create a personal view (that only you can see) or, if you have permissions to do so, you can create a public view for everyone who uses the list to see.

Many lists have other views besides the default view that you see when you first go to the list. To see other views, select the View options menu on the upper right-hand side of the command bar, and then select the view you want and than use **"Edit Current View"**.

[image: View]

In the View settings you can use following conditions using dynamic values to meet your needs. The `[Today]` keyword works on date based columns. You can use math to get ranges that change with today's date.

**Filter - to show only future occurrences:**

Condition: "End Date" is greaten than or equal `[today]`
[image: SharePoint Filter - All Future Events]

**Filter - to show only the next occurrence (in 7 days)**

Condition: "Start Date" is greaten than or equal `[today]` AND "Start Date" is less than or equal `[today]+7`

[image]

You can refer to official MS documentation [Use filtering to modify a SharePoint view](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-filtering-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-3d8efc52-0808-4731-8f9b-3dfaeacea3d4) under "Filter on dynamic dates or current user" section with another example.